# flask socketio not starting

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

Trying to get a flask socketio app going.

Here's my init.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, logging
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from config import app_config

database = SQLAlchemy()
socket_io = SocketIO()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    database.init_app(app)
    socket_io.init_app(app)

    from .home import home as home_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

    return app
```

and here is my run.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from app import create_app, socket_io

config_name = sys.argv[1]
app = create_app(config_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket_io.run(app)
```

When I start up the app, this is the log output in the python console:

```
C:\AnacondaPython\python.exe D:/workspaces/App/run.py development
 * Restarting with windowsapi reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 189-233-458
```

And then nothing happens.

When I open the app in the browser, it just keeps loading.

How do I do this correctly?

I'll provide more code if necessary.

Thanks for any help and tips!

Comment: What is the relationship between this problem and PyCharm? I see you mention it only in the title. Does this work when you run the script outside of PyCharm?

Comment: Hi! Yes, the title is misleading, I have changed it. It doesn't work from the console either. Same behaviour.

Comment: Does the example `app.py` from https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example work in your environment?

Comment: No, same thing unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding your virtual environment?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I didn't even have a virtualenv (I'm new to python). Now it works perfectly AND I'm doing it in a more professional way. Thanks again :)